# REST service basic authentication with php

Tags: php, json, rest

I am trying to use data in json format from REST service.
REST service requires Basic Authentication. 
Here is the code in php:

```
$login = 'username';
$password = 'password!';
$url = 'https://host/rest/serviceLink';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  
echo $result;
```

However, i cant get anything else from the service.

Comment: can u try like this 
$post_data = $login.":".$password;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

Comment: @Mit.agile i've tried, but it does not work for me

Comment: check curl error if(curl_error($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

Comment: @Mit.agile thank you very much. Found the error. Finally it worked!

Comment: @Mit.agile and what was the problem?

Comment: @MaximKorshunov i just guided him to track the issue by finding error using above code so that he can solve it after getting it.

Comment: @MaximKorshunov its not always to give solution on SO here, sometimes you just need to give a guidance to track issue and hence i have put my suggestion as comment and not as answer. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Mit.agile Sorry, i wrongly mentioned You. I wanted to address my question to Aibol. Your answer was actually pretty clear ))

Comment: @MaximKorshunov its alright .. :) Thanks.